# Reading pdf with c# code

Tags: pdf, windows-phone-8

I have pdf file which are uploaded in a web service and I know the Url. I need to open them in my windows phone 8 application. I tried with StorageFile and I got an exception. I think that I have to download first the pdf file and then launch it but I don't know how!

Comment: You can use LaunchUriAsync to open the file: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701484.aspx